# Its respective owners/Their respective owners

Tags: grammatical-number

I'm wondering which one would be grammatically correct. I think both make sense, however, I do think that one is grammatical and the other isn't.

> All credit goes to its respective owners.
>
> All credit goes to their respective owners.

Comment: I agree with @mplungjan that both sentences are nonsense without an indication of what "its" or "theirs" refers to.

Comment: "All credit"...

Answer (score 4):

[Respective](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/respective)

> **adjective**
>   pertaining individually or severally to each of a number of persons, things, etc.; particular: I will now discuss the respective merits of the candidates.

I believe you need to tell us what is owned

> *Here is a video I posted. All credit goes to its respective owners*

meaning two or more people own it (singular)

> *Here are two pictures I posted. All credit goes to their respective owners*

Meaning each picture was owned or copyrighted by a different person

The expression is normally used as

> All Rights Reserved. Exclusively licensed and distributed by Acme inc.. All other trademarks and copyrights are property of their respective owners.

**UPDATE** My suggestions were doubted by Janus who posted

> *“He inherited his shyness and temper from his respective parents”*
>   sounds downright bizarre to me, while
>
> *“They inherited their shyness and temper from their respective parents”*
>   sounds perfectly fine.

If I [nGram](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22his%20respective%20parents%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en) "his respective parents" I get

> 1830: should for the time being be entitled to the actual freehold of the estate so to be charged in possession or in remainder expectant on **his respective parents** decease
>
> 1940: the chief incidence of his jealousy is, of course, partly determined by the biological sex of the child; but it is also in no small measure determined by the state of his emotional relationships with **his respective parents**.
>
> 2008: and each child was interviewed separately with **his respective parents**
>
> 2010: André, with a German-speaking mother and English-speaking father, was spoken to in each language by **his respective parents**

Here is its:

> In principle, each federal ministry prepares regulatory proposals within **its respective competence**

Comment: I don’t think the singular use really holds water, logically. When talking about “their respective owners”, the thing that makes them ‘respective’ is that there are multiple things owned: it means ‘the owners of each individual/particular item’, rather than ‘each individual owner’. If there is only one video (item owned), “All credit goes to its owners” is enough; respective does not make sense. That said, I doubt I’d notice this if I weren’t thinking specifically about it—it’s common enough that I’d just read it and understand it as intended.

Comment: I disagree. Respective refers to owners, not to what they own. The chefs deserve all credit for this wonderful meal ~ all credit goes to its respective creators - the sous-chef and the pastry chef in particular

Comment: That example actually sounds unnatural enough to me that I think I’d react to it even if I weren’t analysing ‘respective’ in my mind already. It really jars. Similarly, “He inherited his shyness and temper from his respective parents” sounds downright bizarre to me, while “They inherited their shyness and temper from their respective parents” sounds perfectly fine.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet What if one of his parents was notably shy and the other was noted to have a temper? I agree it's not the most natural sentence, but it could be grammatical & correct! ;-)

Comment: I disagree when you say "Respective refers to owners, not to what they own". "Respective" *links* each owner in turn with each item or attribute in turn; i.e. it refers to both owner *and* item/attribute. In selected of your examples: 2010: The German-speaking mother spoke to André in German; & the English-speaking father spoke to him in English - linking language & parent. 2008: Child A was interviewed with *his* parents; child B was interviewed with *his* parents; etc.. 1940: also links *each* child with that child's parents. Cont'd ...

Comment: ... cont'd "Here is a video I posted. All credit goes to its respective owners" should just be "... its owners" - there is *one* video with *two owners*, so 'respective' is **not** appropriate. This contrasts with your nGram examples where there were *multiple* children, *each* with two parents. "Respective" requires **at least two** people/items/attributes on **both** sides of the linkage. I have no issue with your pictures or 'Acme' examples.

Comment: Thanks - so what do you suggest I need to change in my description?

Comment: Amplifying my previous comment, "respective" requires an *equal* number (minimum 2) of people/items/attributes (or sets thereof) on each side of the linkage; i.e. a 1:1 relationship. E.g. *each child & respective parents* means one *set of parents* per child; in the 2010 example, it's the 2 parents & 2 languages that are 'respective' (in a 1:1 relationship), not the child. This can become complicated if, say, there are 2 children with the same parents; or 2 pictures with the same owners; but nevertheless there is still a 1:1 relationship between picture & owner or child & parents

Comment: Our last comments overlapped. Primarily, I suggest deleting video example. (2) JBJ's example was not well chosen, but  “He inherited his shyness from his respective parents” would be wrong because there there is a 1:2 relationship. In your 'respective parents' examples there is 1:1 with *each* child and (pair of) parents, so they're OK. 1830 ex. is awkward - appears to mean either "in possession" or "in remainder expectant", depending which parent dies first. *Suggest* also deleting ref. to JBJ, his examples & 1830 ex., retaining rest as usage examples, but modifying nGram intro. Up to you!

Comment: @TrevorD, one shy parent and one tempered (!) was exactly the situation I envisioned when I thought up the example. But even so, it does not work for me at all. I disagree, though, that it must necessarily be a 1:1 relationship—there just has to be more than one of the left-of-the-comma 1s, and then ‘respectively’ denotes the relationship between each 1:X. For example, “The school gave the students surveys to complete, and each student then interviewed their [his/her] respective siblings”—it’s not necessary that it’s always a _1 student:1 sibling_ relationship, but it is [cont’d]

Comment: [cont’d] necessary that there be more than one student in the total set, and that each student is then linked to the unknown/variable set of siblings.

Comment: @Janus See my comment beginning "Amplifying". I specifically said "an equal number ... of people/items/attributes *(or sets thereof)* on each side of the linkage". Hence {1 child : 1 *pair* of parents}; {1 student : 1 *set of* siblings}. I also said you can have "2 children with the same parents; or 2 pictures with the same owner(s)"; or even joint owners. I was trying to emphasise that each item or set on one side *must link* with 1 item or set on the other side **and *vice versa***. I think we're in agreement but expressing it in different ways.